# Styling vertical images differently so they run side-by-side

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, alignment, css-float

I'm building an image gallery and have horizontal and vertical images. At the moment the images load one after the other, stacked vertically.

It works great for the horizontal images, but as soon as I have a vertical image on the layout, it stretches to match the width of the horizontal ones and becomes too high to fit the screen.

I'm trying to find a solution to always align 2 vertical images side-by-side.

Here's some graphics to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

[Image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16452683/transfer/imageflow.jpg) <- I'm sorry I can't post images.

Ideally there would be a solution using CSS only, but I don't think it will be possible. So, I gave it a go using some jQuery.

```
$('.image-wrapper').prop('height', function(){
if($(this).height() > $(this).width()){
    //portrait, resize accordingly
    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();
    $(this).css({"width": "50%", "float": "left"});
});
```

The only problem with this solution is that it doesn't take the DIV's margins into consideration. And I can't find a way to compensate for it.

Here's a link to [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gugavieira/dsfa2bvu/35/)

**UPDATE**:

I've tweaked the jQuery to test wether or not the previous image is vertical and add the margin between them. I'm just wondering how reliable this solution is.

Here's a link to the [Fiddle][4]

As a bonus it would be great to be able to check how many vertical images I have in a sequence and position all of them side-by-side. ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Where should do vertical images go?

Comment: why not just put float:left on each of the vertical images? no need for jquery. .vertical{float:left; width:50%}

Comment: @eugensunic They should go bellow the horizontal ones. The image I linked should give you a better idea of what I mean.

Comment: @BragDeal I don't have access to the HTML and either the horizontal and vertical images have the same CSS classes. I'm tweaking one of those Squarespace themes.

Comment: The image redirects to some URL?

Comment: Upload an example (picture, does't have to be the real one) .

Comment: @eugensunic I'm sorry, I fixed the link to the image. But here it is again just in case: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16452683/transfer/imageflow.jpg

Comment: see the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/dsfa2bvu/41/ ,what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**

You mentioned you don't have access to the html. In order to access the css of the n-th element, you can user nth-of-type(x) selector.

Here is some info about it: 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

Using only the css, add this:

```
.image-wrapper:nth-of-type(2),.image-wrapper:nth-of-type(3){
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

and remove your js. This should do it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dsfa2bvu/39/

**Option 2:**

Using Jquery, locate the word "vertical" in each image. Once found, add a style to it.

Here is how to locate it:

```
var x = $("img[src$='vertical-img']");
x.css("float","left");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dsfa2bvu/40/

Comment: Thanks Brag. That's a great technique, but I won't always know the n-th of the vertical images. Sometimes it will be the 2nd and the 3d, sometimes the 10th and 11th and so on.

Comment: Brad? :p There is so much you can do without access to html when having the same class names. The only other thought I have is, locate the word "vertical" in every image, and using js and add the needed styling to it

Comment: Sorry, Brag ;) I guess I've been struggling with this for too long. Time to have break.

You mean locate the word "vertical" in the file name? This could be an interesting approach.

Comment: Updated my answer. You locate the image you need (assuming the image has the word vertical-img in it, then you style it

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
$('.thumb-image').each(function (i, obj) {
        if ($(this).width() > $(this).eq(i + 1).width()) {
            $('.thumb-image').slice(i + 1).each(function () {

                $(this).css({
                    float: "left",
                    width: "50%",
                    padding: "0",
                    margin: "0"


                });
            });
        }

    });
```

fiddle **EDIT**: http://jsfiddle.net/dsfa2bvu/41/

Comment: Very elegant solution Eugen. Is there a way to add the 20px margin between the vertical images?

Comment: I was trying something along these lines: http://jsfiddle.net/gugavieira/a2jkfjqz/17/

Comment: I see that you've got it working with your example.Well yes you could, however you would have to go with a if stat. to adjust the left with a margin right and the right with a margin left, but i believe you would have to change the wrapper as well. If I find's some time tomorrow, will do that if you still want.

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you have some spare time tomorrow. I'll keep you posted if I find anything in the meanwhile. Thanks